# What is the value of JAVA_HOME for CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, java, redhat, yum

I have install java through yum on CentOS, however another java programme needs to know what the JAVA_HOME environmental variable is. I know all about setting environmental variables, but what do I set it to? `java` is installed in `/usr/bin/java`, it can't be there!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Actually I found it,

it's `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/`. I found out what it was by doing `update-alternatives --display java` and it showed me the directory `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`

Answer (score 20):

I'm not quite sure but if you install the normal RPMS the JAVA_HOME value can also be set to this:

```
/usr/java/default/
```

EDIT: I just checked on my home system. I have created this file:

```
/etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

That contains:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default/
```

and I'm using the official version from Sun: jdk-1.6.0_12-fcs

**EDIT:** Here is [how I set up Java on my machine](http://howto.basjes.nl/linux/installing-my-new-server/Various-software):

### Install Java

Download and install Java JDK from Oracle

### Make it primary

Ensure this Java is used instead of the OpenJDK version using the following two commands:

#### First

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/default/bin/java 999999 \
           --slave /usr/bin/keytool keytool /usr/java/default/bin/keytool \
           --slave /usr/bin/rmiregistry rmiregistry /usr/java/default/bin/rmiregistry
```

#### Second

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/default/bin/javac 999999 \
           --slave /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/default/bin/jar \
           --slave /usr/bin/rmic rmic /usr/java/default/bin/rmic
```

### Set JAVA_HOME

Ensure all users have their JAVA_HOME environment variable set to the correct value:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default/" > /etc/profile.d/java_home.sh
```

Comment: oh interesting. :)

Comment: There's no `/usr/java/default` in my CentOS 6 box with OpenJDK 1.6 and 1.7 installed.

Comment: @DanielSerodio Correct. I clearly described "Download and install Java JDK from Oracle", and then it does exist.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set JAVA_HOME to be the root location of the JDK or JRE, for example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.3
```

If the JDK (Development kit) is installed, ypu probably want it to point to that, else use the JRE path (Java Runtime Environment).  Then, you might want to set your $PATH environment variable to include the bin directory as well:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.3/bin
```

If you are using tomcat, you might also need to set CATALINA_HOME for the tomcat user.

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/path/to/tomcat
```

To set this for the system you want to edit your /etc/profile or add a .sh file in /etc/profile.d folder.  For a particular user you can put it in the users ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile files.

Comment: I wonder if there is a good reason the install doesn't do this for you if run as the super user, I always find it irritating ...

Answer (score 2):

Below is always working for me perfectly:

```
[user@base ~]$ locate bin/java
/usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/javac
/usr/bin/javadoc
/usr/bin/javaws
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javac
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javadoc
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javah
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javap
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javaws
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/bin/java
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/bin/java_vm
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/bin/javaws
```

It means I can set JAVA_HOME as /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31

Answer (score 2):

I considered the problem of if one changes the version of java being used with:

```
alternatives --config java
```

Then any hard coded `JAVA_HOME` is going to change (atleast it will on the Centos 6.6 I'm currently staring at).  That is, there is no `/usr/java`.

This doesn't seem like the best way (open to failure) but in the 10 mins I've spent on this it seems the best.

In `/etc/bashrc` I modified the setting to `JAVA_HOME` to be:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(alternatives --display java | grep current | sed 's/link currently points to //' | sed 's|/bin/java||')
```

You have to do something similar on MacOSX but without all the `grep` and `sed` to parse out the result.  Surely `alternatives` offers an similarly easier solution.

Anyways I hope I helped.

---

***Update***

No that would be `JRE_HOME`.  The JDK / SDK isn't proving as obvious (I'll keep looking).

The `alternatives` seems to only be about the JRE by default.  I defer to @Niels answer or just install Java with `yum` and set the JAVA_HOME to that (the trick is where I found where that was installed to!).

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

I noticed `java_1.8.0` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0` and so set my $JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java_1.8.0`.  In the `/etc/bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats weird, the whole point of having a JAVE_HOME environmental variable is so you don't have to specify the path to each program, it can get this path by looking for this variable.

Either way, the correct way to find the environmental variable for JAVA_HOME is to use echo:

```
[root@host ~]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_09
```

Running this command will display the path no matter what version you are running, from command line.

Comment: The variable had not been set.

Answer (score 0):

re: Centos7, refer to the /etc/java/java.conf file.

in it JAVA_HOME is indicated to be located in the following dir : /usr/lib/jvm/java

i checked, it is the correct version of the jdk I loaded via yum, and so...

my env doesn't have JAVA_HOME set by default, therefore I set it in .bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

I found the package manager can place in a variety of locations, so using *which* (you will need to explicitly install this if using a container) the following is a little less brittle

```
javaCompiler=$(which javac)
javaBin=$(dirname $(readlink -f $javaCompiler))
javaHome=${javaBin%/*}
export JAVA_HOME=$javaHome
```

or for JRE

```
javaExec=$(which java)
javaBin=$(dirname $(readlink -f $javaExec))
javaHome=${javaBin%/*}
export JRE_HOME=$javaHome
```